# pandas changing wide data to long data with suffixes from negative to positive numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to coding and I would like help to transform data in a wide format to long format using Pandas.
However using `pd.wide_to_long` didn't achieve my desired output

What I have:

[How it looks in Wide format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4I5Y.png)

However I need it in this format:

[How it should look in Long format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzJxG.png)

I have tried `pd.wide_to_long(df, ['quarter_'],'Deal_Number', 'quarter_to_date')` however the best it gives me is the 'quarter_to_date' column only going from 0 to 4 and not including the negatives (-4 to -1)

I have also tried renaming the  columns with double underscores '__' to '_-' but it still doesn't include them.

Can't figure out how to make this, even tried adding the `suffix='\w|\d+'`  to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly negative values are not supported in `wide_to_long`, so need another solutions.

```
#change column names
df = (df.rename(columns={'quarter':'quarter_0'})
       .rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('__','_-')))

#create MultiIndex with column with no quarters
df = df.set_index(['Deal_Number','AcquierName_clean'])
#create MultiIndex in columns
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
#reshape by stack
df = df.stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'quarter_'})
#convert column to integers
df['quarter_'] = df['quarter_'].astype(int)
#if necessary sorting
df = df.sort_values(['Deal_Number','AcquierName_clean','quarter_'])
```

---

```
print (df)
    Deal_Number AcquierName_clean  quarter_  quarter
3             0             BankA        -4   198009
2             0             BankA        -3   198012
1             0             BankA        -2   198103
0             0             BankA        -1   198106
4             0             BankA         0   198109
5             0             BankA         1   198112
6             0             BankA         2   198203
7             0             BankA         3   198206
8             0             BankA         4   198209
12            1             BankB        -4   198106
11            1             BankB        -3   198109
10            1             BankB        -2   198112
9             1             BankB        -1   198203
13            1             BankB         0   198206
14            1             BankB         1   198209
15            1             BankB         2   198212
16            1             BankB         3   198303
17            1             BankB         4   198306
21            2             BankC        -4   198206
20            2             BankC        -3   198209
19            2             BankC        -2   198212
18            2             BankC        -1   198303
22            2             BankC         0   198306
23            2             BankC         1   198309
24            2             BankC         2   198312
25            2             BankC         3   198403
26            2             BankC         4   198406
```

Comment: This is great! However to make it more extendable, what if there are columns where the names include Underscores, e.g. 'Bank_Loan_Amount_1' etc ? I have had the idea to rename it so that it is without the underscores, then renaming it back at the end, although there must be a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pd.melt`.

I've taken a sample of the dataframe you posted, and tried to produce the result. You can do it for all your columns:

Below is the dataframe I used:

```
In [970]: df
Out[970]: 
  Acquirer  Deal_Number  quarter  quarter_1  quarter_2
0   Bank A            0   198109     198106     198103
1   Bank B            1   198206     198203     198112
2   Bank C            2   198306     198303     198212

In [969]: pd.melt(df,id_vars=['Deal_Number','Acquirer'], var_name='quarter', value_name="values").sort_values('Deal_Number').replace({'quarter'
     ...: :{'quarter':0, 'quarter_1': -1, 'quarter_2': -2, 'quarter_3': -3, 'quarter_4': -4}})

Out[969]: 
   Deal_Number Acquirer  quarter  values
0            0   Bank A        0  198109
3            0   Bank A       -1  198106
6            0   Bank A       -2  198103
1            1   Bank B        0  198206
4            1   Bank B       -1  198203
7            1   Bank B       -2  198112
2            2   Bank C        0  198306
5            2   Bank C       -1  198303
8            2   Bank C       -2  198212
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi, this is great! Thank you! However, for larger data frames it might not be as extendable to rename all the rows later. Do you know any function which might rename them more efficiently? Thank you